# is it possible to push SMS messages to phones nearby?

Tags: android, iphone, mobile, sms

I was wondering if it is possible to push SMS messages to phones nearby. Like advertising for a product. I am not sure if it is illegal or not, but I am just curious if it is possible and how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible..You need to have a client which share users location to a web app..The web app based on the location sends sms through some sms gateway to all the nearby users...

And is you are a carrier/network provider you can send sms to all the users in a particular cell.

Answer (score 1):

Thankfully, no.  You'd need their numbers, which unless they've signed up for a service isn't really possible.  Not to mention anyone who implemented such a feature should be beat to death for doing so.